# TextView vs Button for Android AlertDialog

Tags: android, xml

I want to open an `AlertDialog` on the click of either a `Button` or `TextView` but I am not sure what would work best. When a selection is made in the `AlertDialog`, I want the bottom text to be updated with the selection. Here are the two options I have:

`TextView`s only. Here, the `LinearLayout` will have listener and will open `AlertDialog`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Select..." />

</LinearLayout>
```

`TextView` and `Button`. Here, the `Button` will open the `AlertDialog` and the text inside the `Button` will be replaced with the selection.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="Label"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:text="Select..."
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is Button.

Button is a subclass of TextView. So it has all the features of TextView and additional features of Button class. Button adds a few stylistic changes (e.g., default background image, additional padding, ripple effect) to allow quicker adaptation to your designs.